# Issues with NDSolve in using methods

Tags: differential-equations

```
 trajData = {{0, 0.002`}, {1, 0.002`}, {2, 0.002`}, {3, 0.002`}, {4, 
0.002`}, {5, 0.002`}, {6, 0.006`}, {7, 0.004`}, {8, 0.004`}, {9, 
0.004`}, {10, 0.006`}, {11, 0.006`}, {12, 0.01`}, {13, 
0.014`}, {14, 0.016`}, {15, 0.008`}, {16, 0.012`}, {17, 
0.018`}, {18, 0.024`}, {19, 0.022`}, {20, 0.012`}, {21, 
0.01`}, {22, 0.006`}, {23, 0.008`}, {24, 0.006`}, {25, 
0.004`}, {26, 0.002`}, {27, 0.002`}, {28, 0.002`}, {29, 
0.002`}, {30, 0.004`}, {31, 0.006`}, {32, 0.004`}, {33, 
0.01`}, {34, 0.016`}, {35, 0.028`}, {36, 0.022`}, {37, 
0.016`}, {38, 0.008`}, {39, 0.014`}, {40, 0.012`}, {41, 
0.008`}, {42, 0.006`}, {43, 0.006`}, {44, 0.008`}, {45, 
0.008`}, {46, 0.004`}, {47, 0.01`}, {48, 0.012`}, {49, 
0.016`}, {50, 0.014`}, {51, 1}, {52, 1}, {53, 1}, {54, 1}, {55, 
1}, {56, 1}, {57, 1}, {58, 1}, {59, 1}, {60, 1}, {61, 1}, {62, 
1}, {63, 1}, {64, 1}, {65, 1}, {66, 1}, {67, 1}, {68, 1}, {69, 
1}, {70, 1}, {71, 1}, {72, 1}, {73, 1}, {74, 1}, {75, 1}, {76, 
1}, {77, 1}, {78, 1}, {79, 1}, {80, 1}, {81, 1}, {82, 1}, {83, 
1}, {84, 1}, {85, 1}, {86, 1}, {87, 1}, {88, 1}, {89, 1}, {90, 
1}, {91, 1}, {92, 1}, {93, 1}, {94, 1}, {95, 1}, {96, 1}, {97, 
1}, {98, 1}, {99, 1}, {100, 1}};

  N1 = 500;
  s = 0.05;
  x0 = 1/(s N1);
  theta = 0.1;

  gValues = {};

   trajInterpolation = Interpolation[trajData];
   G = NDSolveValue[{D[g[x, t], 
  t] == (x (1 - x))/(2 N1*trajInterpolation[t]) D[g[x, t], x, x], 
    g[1, t] == 0, 
    g[0, t] == trajInterpolation[t] theta (1 - Exp[-10000000 t]), 
     g[x, 0] == 0}, g, {t, 0, 100}, {x, 0, 1}];
    Close[trajFile];
     gValues = Table[G[x, 50], {x, 0.01, 1, 0.01}];

      ListPlot[Transpose[{Range[0.01, 1, 0.01], gValues}],       Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "Average g(x, 50)"}, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.005], Black]]
```

Comment: Please describe the problems you are encountering.

Comment: Hi @EricBrown could you please tell why I still have -2 on this question? I have now provided all the data required to reproduce.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you so much for the help! Below Michael has perfectly solved the problem. It was creating problem for me that the data generated was completely junk

Comment: @SachinKaushik Probably drive-by voters.  They may return later and remove their downvotes when they see you've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examine `Plot[trajInterpolation[t], {t, 0, 50}, PlotRange -> All]`. There's a big spike before `t == 50`, which looks suspicious and potentially error-incurring. Maybe you should try `InterpolationOrder -> 1` on `trajInterpolation`. Your non-monotonic data suggests that a higher order is unlikely to be more accurate.  (You might try fitting a model to it, if there is an model for this process, whatever it is; the data is pretty noisy, so this suggestion is probably a non-starter.)  Maybe use `Piecewise` to define the trajectory function for `t >= 50` and interpolation to define it below 50.  The big jump from small values to `1` will also incur error in the solution.  `Piecewise` will model the rise as a sudden jump, and `NDSolve` will use discontinuity processing to handle it.

```
trajInterpolation = Interpolation[trajData, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
trajPW = Piecewise[{{trajInterpolation[t], t < 50}}, 1];
G = NDSolveValue[{D[g[x, t], 
      t] == (x (1 - x))/(2 N1*trajPW) D[g[x, t], x, x], g[1, t] == 0, 
    g[0, t] == trajPW* theta (1 - Exp[-10000000 t]), g[x, 0] == 0}, 
   g, {t, 0, 100}, {x, 0, 1}];
(*Close[trajFile];*)
gValues = Table[G[x, 50], {x, 0.01, 1, 0.01}];

ListPlot[Transpose[{Range[0.01, 1, 0.01], gValues}], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "Average g(x, 50)"}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.005], Black]]
```

[image]

You use the solution only up to `t == 50` so why integrate past that? If there is a reason, then perhaps `Piecewise` is an inappropriate choice.

Comment: Thank you so much Michael for the thorough clarification, it really helped.  Indeed trajInterpolation should be handled carefully, I thought it was the issue of NDSolve. Thank you!!!